# `for .. in KafkaConsumer`: how to survive `eof`?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

```
for consumed_record in KafkaConsumer(config.kafka_topic,                                      
                                     bootstrap_servers=config.kafka_bootstrap_servers,
                                     group_id=config.kafka_group_id):
        __process_kafka_record(consumed_record)
```

The code above works fine except when `EOF` is seen. Then `for` loop terminates, however that's not the behaviour I'd like. I want my consumer to run endlessly unless the entire process dies. Conceptually I need something like `if is_eof(): continue`. What's the right way to do that with `python-kafka` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python).

The correct way to consume records is to wrap that loop inside another loop that only stops if you want to.

The kafka-python project contains a few [examples](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/example.py#L35-L46), like:

```python
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
consumer.subscribe(['my-topic'])

while not self.stop_event.is_set():
    for message in consumer:
        print(message)
        if self.stop_event.is_set():
            break

consumer.close()
```